# How to store both fixed and variable attributes as a feature class?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, attribute-table

I have a live data feeds as an XML file from the Internet. I need to use Python and ArcPy lib to store each feed as a point feature in a feature class of an ArcSDE datbase.

The xml looks like:

```
<array-list>
    <spider-pos-wSVO brigade-no="36145" heading="280" altitude="302" longitude="146.09046833333332" latitude="-37.054605" personnel-no="0" speed="13">
        <attrA>12</attrA>
        <attrB>0</attrB>
    </spider-pos-wSVO>
    <spider-pos-wSVO brigade-no="36145" heading="280" altitude="302" longitude="146.09046833333332" latitude="-37.054605" personnel-no="0" speed="13">
        <attrA>12</attrA>
        <attrC>0</attrC>
    </spider-pos-wSVO>
    <spider-pos-wSVO brigade-no="36145" heading="280" altitude="302" longitude="146.09046833333332" latitude="-37.054605" personnel-no="0" speed="13">
        <attrA>12</attrA>
        <attrD>0</attrD>
    </spider-pos-wSVO>
    ....
</array-list>
```

Obviously each  element has a fixed set of attributes (heading, altitude, longitude and latitude, etc etc) and a various set of child-elements (attrA, attrB, attrC and attrD, etc). I am able to store the fixed attributes as attribute fields in the SDE feature class but have no idea how and where to store the variable ones.

Has anyone got a best practise for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a [Entity–attribute–value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (EAV) data model.

There are many negatives to using this data model, but in cases like this, it is the only option.

The basic theory is that you have a table with the fixed attributes, and you have an additional table to store the additional(variable) attributes.

In your case, the main table cane be something like:
`spider_pos(spider_id, brigade_no, heading, altitude,  longitude, latitude, personnel_no, speed)`

where `spider_id` is the primary key of the table. Make sure you don't use ObjectIDs for this, since you have no control over them.

Your variable data table will be something like this:

`spider_data(spider_id, attribute_name, value)`

Please note that I don't know about your data, so the names might not be really appropriate. Secondly, I don't know if time is involved. If it is, then you need to store that as well.

Additionally, read this [wonderful answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5809/442) by @underdark, which talks about how such a system us used for a temporal Meteorological database.